# Multiple processes in one button

Tags: c#, button, webclient, zip

First of all hello guys i just wanted to add button that downloads zip files from link and then unzips and i ran into problems i get this error:

> "System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file
> 'C:\GTA\TEST.zip' because it is being used by another process.'"

It looks really simple but i can't solve it so i hope you guys help me. this is code:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string root = @"C:\GTA";
        //this if directory doesn't exist
        if (!Directory.Exists(root))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
        }

        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        WebClient webcl = new WebClient();
        webcl.DownloadFileCompleted += Webcl_DownloadFileCompleted;
        webcl.DownloadProgressChanged += Webcl_DownloadProgressChanged;
        webcl.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://download1474.mediafire.com/17r5hin4vceg/izkb8vk7pudg5g4/TEST.zip"), @"C:\GTA\TEST.zip");

        string targetfolder = @"C:\GTA\UNZIPEDFolder";
        string sourceZipFile = @"C:\GTA\TEST.zip";
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(sourceZipFile, targetfolder);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert here, however you get the file asynchronosly without awaiting it.
DownloadFileAsync

So you make a call to extract the file while it's being downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You calling `ExtractToDirectory` before file will be actually downloaded, as file downloading is async. So, you need to `await` when downloading process will finish. To do so, you will need the following

- make the whole event click handler `async` - `private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`.
- replace `DownloadFileAsync` which returns `void` and thus is not `async/await`-friendly with `DownloadFileTaskAsync`, which is awaitable.
- Then you will able to `await` downloading with `await webcl.DownloadFileTaskAsync(...args here...);`
- finally, you can remove `DownloadFileCompleted` subscription, as you may be sure that after `await` the file downloading is completed.

By the way, `WebClient` is considered as an old API and is not recommended for using in the new code. You may consider to switch to `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a bit on the two previous answers, you are in fact trying to unzip the file before you have downloaded it. You should change your code as follows:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string root = @"C:\GTA";
    //this if directory doesn't exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(root))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
    }

    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    WebClient webcl = new WebClient();
    webcl.DownloadFileCompleted += Webcl_DownloadFileCompleted;
    webcl.DownloadProgressChanged += Webcl_DownloadProgressChanged;

    await webcl.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://download1474.mediafire.com/17r5hin4vceg/izkb8vk7pudg5g4/TEST.zip"), @"C:\GTA\TEST.zip");

    string targetfolder = @"C:\GTA\UNZIPEDFolder";
    string sourceZipFile = @"C:\GTA\TEST.zip";
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(sourceZipFile, targetfolder);
}
```

Note the `async` as well as the `await` before `DownloadFileAsync()`.

Additionally, you might want to refactor that a bit and move the download / unzip part out of the Button Event Handler.

Comment: thanks for helping but now i have this error 
Error CS4033 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'

Comment: Please check your `button2_Click` method declaration carefully and compare it with sample provided above. Make sure that `async` modifier is not missing.

Comment: Now it says can't await void :(

Comment: Hm, I just realized that you are using old WebClient, which is not recommended to use in a modern applications. Are you really have some strict reasons to use  old WebClient instead of modern HttpClient? If yes, then you will need to use `DownloadFileTaskAsync` to get await-friendly behaviout. Or you may consider to swithing to modern `HttpClient`. And I updated my answer accordingly.